# How to make a view's height animate from 0 to height in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I'd like to make this bar's height (part of a larger bar graph) animate on appear from 0 to its given height, but I can't quite figure it out in SwiftUI? I found this code that was helpful, but with this only the first bar (of 7) animates:

```
struct BarChartItem: View {
    
    var value: Int
    var dayText: String
    var topOfSCaleColorIsRed: Bool
    
    @State var growMore: CGFloat = 0
    @State var showMore: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(value)%")
                .font(Font.footnote.monospacedDigit())
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
                .fill(getBarColor())
                .frame(width: 40, height: growMore)
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 7.0)) {
                            growMore = CGFloat(value)
                            showMore = 1
                        }
                    }
                }.opacity(showMore)
            Text(dayText.uppercased())
                .font(.caption)
            
            
        }
        
    }
```

And this is the chart:

```
 HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    ForEach(pastRecoveryScoreObjects) { pastRecoveryScoreObject in
                        BarChartItem(value: pastRecoveryScoreObject.recoveryScore, dayText: "\(pastRecoveryScoreObject.date.weekdayName)", topOfSCaleColorIsRed: false)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What is the code for your other bars?

Comment: @aheze please see my addition at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works: you can get the index of the ForEach loop and delay each bar's animation by some time * that index. All the bars are connected to the same state variable via a binding, and the state is set immediately on appear. You can play with the parameters to tune it to your own preferences.

```
struct TestChartAnimationView: View {
    let values = [200, 120, 120, 90, 10, 80]
    @State var open = false
    
    var animationTime: Double = 0.25
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                ForEach(values.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    BarChartItem(open: $open, value: values[index])
                        .animation(
                            Animation.linear(duration: animationTime).delay(animationTime * Double(index))
                        )
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                open = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BarChartItem: View {
    @Binding var open: Bool
    var value: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(value)%")
                .font(Font.footnote.monospacedDigit())
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 20, height: open ? CGFloat(value) : 0)
            Text("Week".uppercased())
                .font(.caption)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  this works pretty well, except the views build from the top down, is there a way to make them grow from bottom up?

Comment: when I ran it they go from bottom to top, because I put them in a vstack with a spacer. Try moving the spacer below if you want the opposite direction

Comment:  I did try with a vstack and a spacer on either side but same result, can't figure out why it would behave differently as our code seems to be identical ‍♂️

Comment: To build from bottom up, you will need to insert a `.transition()` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: ForEach animations are kind of weird. I'm not sure why, but this works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let values = [200, 120, 120, 90, 10, 80]
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            ForEach(values, id: \.self) { value in
                BarChartItem(totalValue: value)
                    .animation(.linear(duration: 3))
            }
        }
    }
}
struct BarChartItem: View {
    @State var value: Int = 0
    var totalValue = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(value)%")
                .font(Font.footnote.monospacedDigit())
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 20, height: CGFloat(value))
            Text("Week".uppercased())
                .font(.caption)
            
        }.onAppear {
            value = totalValue
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of applying the animation in the `onAppear`, I applied an implicit animation inside the `ForEach`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to show an animation so that each bar in the chart animates from bottom of the screen to top one after another.

Comment: sorry if I am not clear, it's hard to articulate but picture that the graph on appear, beginning from the bottom the first bar will grow to it's height, then the next bar until all bars have grown to their height.  Rather than start in the middle and grow up and down (as is in your animation), they should start at the very bottom and only grow up.

Comment: Ah, so kind of like one by one too? @bze12's answer might work